# Copy an Xml Attribute with Linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, odt

I have following xml structure with namespaces:

```
<office:document-content
<office:body>
<office:text text:use-soft-page-breaks="true">
  <text:p text:style-name="Standard">&lt;Text&gt;</text:p>
</office:text>
</office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

This comes from the content.xml of an unzipped .odt writer file. Now I just want to copy the attribute with the inner text "<Text>" and replace the copy with a new text. I tried this:

```
    XmlFileOperations xml = new XmlFileOperations();
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(Path.Combine(ConfigManager.InputPath, "File", "content.xml"));

        var source = doc.Descendants()
            .Where(e => e.Value == "<Text>")
            .FirstOrDefault();
        var target = new XElement(source);
        target.Add(new XAttribute("Standard", source.Attribute(textLine)));

        doc.Save(Path.Combine(ConfigManager.InputPath, "File", "content.xml"));
```

This does not work. It tells me that I have a sign in the text which can not be applied to the name. How I can just copy my attribute in this case?

Thank you!

Edit: The result should be

```
<office:document-content
<office:body>
<office:text text:use-soft-page-breaks="true">
  <text:p text:style-name="Standard">&lt;Text&gt;</text:p>
  <text:p text:style-name="Standard">some new value</text:p>
</office:text>
</office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you need the value of `<Text>` replace with `textLine`.

Try this code

```
var source = doc.Descendants()
    .Where(e => !e.HasElements && e.Value == "<Text>")
    .FirstOrDefault();

var target = new XElement(source);
target.Value = textLine;
source.AddAfterSelf(target);

doc.Save(...);
```

Comment: Not only. I need to copy the attribute so that I have two identical attributes and then replace the value of the copy.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
         
            XElement doc = XElement.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement p = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "p").FirstOrDefault();
            XAttribute name = p.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "style-name").FirstOrDefault();
            name.Value = "new value";
            doc.Save(FILENAME);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess this is not exactly what I'm looking for because the value gets changed but there is no new attribute created. I edited my question. Hope now it's more clear